# sharepoint 2010 - creation of master document template and reusing

Tags: sharepoint-online

Our department has few document templates used to capture product information and details.
 We what to maintain the master template in sharepoint2010.

The requirement is –

When the user select the word template to enter product information and details, the template should open and the user should be able to enter the values, details etc.. and save /upload the doc to the SharePoint location.

The master template needs to be as it is without changes but the copies created need to be uploaded to SP.

We tried to simulate this by following info from the web – creating document templates in Sharepoint2010.

We could see the option for the document under “Create Document” - > new document, template document. When we select template document, it is not opening up the document for editing.

Answer (score 1):

You should create content types for this and upload the templates to the content type for it to use. Then when they go to the library, they can simply click New>Document (or whatever you call the content type).

Answer (score -1):

The users with the possibility to use several templates in the same library
The procedure is simple by creating the content type inheriting from the document Library for each template. and add the same content type to the library you needed.
For more details, please refer below URL:
http://nubo.eu/office365/scappelletti/add-several-document-templates-sharepoint-online-library/

Comment: Can you please add some brief description from the link which have mentioned.